# If two neutron stars of opposite spin collide will the resulting body have less mass due to lack of rotational energy?

Tags: gravity, mass-energy, rotation

If two neutron stars of opposite spin collide will the resulting body have less mass due to lack of rotational energy? Will the Penrose proccess lead to less gravitational mass?

Answer (score 1):

Mass-energy is conserved but there will be ejecta and radiation,
which will transport mass-energy away from the (gravitationally bound part of the) object. I don't see any relevance of the Penrose process to this question, a neutron star is not a black hole and there's no need to invoke exotic processes to find mass-energy outside of the event horizon: *all* the mass-energy of a neutron star is outside the event horizon.